# How to permission (disallow) smart contract deployment on private Ethereum network?

Tags: contract-deployment, private-blockchain, permissioned-chain

On a private Ethereum network, what is the best way to permission the deployment of who (and what) users can deploy?

One obvious way would be increasing the gas cost of `CREATE` opcode. Yet, I do not like sending a lot of ETH in order to allow the deployment of a SC.

Can this be controlled via another smart contract or would changes to the node software be needed?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can see there are no nice approaches. I can think of the following:

1) Increase gas cost

2) Add logic to nodes to not mine such transactions. Also don't broadcast them.

3) Disallow (remove?) the `CREATE` (and `CREATE2`) opcode completely in nodes

4) Set block gas limit low enough so it can't include contracts. I guess 21000 is always enough in that case.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested this yet but I found something.

https://openethereum.github.io/Permissioning#transaction-type

Using the openethereum client. you can add permissions on different layers. One of the layer is transaction-type(contract-deployment,contract-interaction,simple transfer).